# How to properly handle DB query errors in Next 14 server-side components?

Tags: next.js, server

I have a server-side component making several queries to the DB.

I make each call sequentially and if either fails I return a div with some info on which query failed.

```
async function Details({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const id = Number(params.id);

  const data1 = await prismadb.model1.findUnique({ where: { id } });

  if (data1 === null) {
    return <div>Missing Data 1</div>;
  }

  const data2 = await prismadb.model2.findUnique({ where: { id } });

  if (data2 === null) {
    return <div>Missing Data 2</div>;
  }

  return (
    {/* Lots of divs with data from data1 and/or data2 */}
  );
}
```

Problem:

- it's ugly
- adding queries would make it even worse

So how should these DB queries be handled in Next?

Another approach could be to use a custom hook that would perform all DB queries and return some info if an error happens.

```
const useData1and2 = (id: number) => {
  const data1 = await prismadb.model1.findUnique({ where: { id } });

  if (data1 === null) {
    return { data: {}, error: 'Missing Data 1' };
  }

  const data2 = await prismadb.model2.findUnique({ where: { id } });

  if (data2 === null) {
    return { data: {}, error: 'Missing Data 2' };
  }

  return { data: { data1, data2 }, error: '' };
}
```

Then I could check if there is an error in the above component and display some message. But this doesn't change the logic of the code, it just puts it somewhere else.

Comment: I dont see whats the problem here, you have to make queries and add proper validation to the follows also this code is running on the server not on clients local machine.

Comment: 'follows' as in return values or something else?